# I want to change from a click event to a keypress event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a to do list and have it set to add the item when you click the add button but I want to make it to where you can press enter and here is my code:

```
function addListItem() {
    var text = $("#new-text").val();
    $("#todolist").append('<li><input type="checkbox" class="done"/>'+text+'<button                  class="delete">Delete</button></li>');
    $("#new-text").val('');
}

$(function() {
    $("#add").on('keypress' , addListItem);
}
```

please help

Answer (score 1):

You can do something such this inside of your addListItem Function:

**JS:**

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        alert('You pressed enter!');
    }
});
```

As your implementation:

```
function addListItem(event) {
    if(event.which == 13){
        var text = $("#new-text").val();
        $("#todolist").append('<li><input type="checkbox" class="done"/>'+text+'<button                  class="delete">Delete</button></li>');
        $("#new-text").val('');
    }
}

$(function() {
    $("#add").on('keypress' , function(event) { addListItem(event););
}
```

Comment: `$("#add").on('keypress' , addListItem(this));` is wrong

Comment: Now it's fixed, thanks:
$('#add').on('keypress', function(event) { addListItem(event); });

Comment: You do not even need the function...

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
function addListItem(event) {
    if(event.which == 13){

        var text = $("#new-text").val();
        $("#todolist").append('<li><input type="checkbox" class="done"/>'+text+'<button                  class="delete">Delete</button></li>');
        $("#new-text").val('');
    }
}

$(function() {
    $("#add").on('keypress' , addListItem);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the `keyCode` in your function:

```
function something(event){
  if ( event.keyCode == 13 ) 
    alert( 'ENTER!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the keycode you pressed and check it is the ENTER key.

```
function addListItem(e) {
    var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (keycode == '13') {
        var text = $("#new-text").val();
        $("#todolist").append('<li><input type="checkbox" class="done"/>'+text+'<button                  class="delete">Delete</button></li>');
        $("#new-text").val('');
        $("#new-text").val('');
    }
});
```